# Why not able to add proctime by call addColumns?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

```
tableEnv.fromDataStream(xxxStream).addColumns('processTime.proctime)
```

The above code will throw excetion:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Window properties can only be used on windowed tables.
```

but this will works

```
tableEnv.fromDataStream(xxxStream, 'id,  ......, 'processTime.proctime)
```

But I must repeat all the columns in this way.

Comment: Same issue on recent 1.14.3 version. Did you found any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Found some workaround for that, not sure if it could be done easier though:

```
Table tmpTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(my_pojo_datastream);
Schema newSchema = Schema.newBuilder()
   .fromResolvedSchema(tmpTable.getResolvedSchema())
   .columnByExpression("proc_time", "PROCTIME()")
   .build();

Table tmpTableWithProcTIme = tableEnv.fromDataStream(my_pojo_datastream, newSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me

```
Table tmpTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(my_pojo_datastream,
          Schema.newBuilder().columnByExpression("proc_time", "PROCTIME()").build());
```